# @Produces("application/json") doesn't work in RestEasy

Tags: java, json, jackson, resteasy

My code is like this

```
@Path("/TestClass")
public class Test implements Serializable {

  @GET
  @Path("/hello")
  public Response heloMessage() {

    String output = "Hello Word!!!!!!!!!";

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/get")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public EmailJobData getProductInJSON() {

    EmailJobData product = new EmailJobData();
      product.setBody("Test");
      product.setHost("Test data");;

      return product; 

  }
```

My web.xml file is totall empty. I have created a class and extends **javax.ws.rs.core.Application**

The heloMessage function works okay when I go to

> http://localhost:8080/RemoteQuartzScheduler/rest/TestClass/hello

Like that when I tries to go to

> http://localhost:8080/RemoteQuartzScheduler/rest/TestClass/get

to access the getProductInJSON function, nothing happens. No error message, nothing... When I debug also, it doesn't come inside to the function either.

What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check what is response type which you are setting up in the client. Is it JSON type or XML or plain text

Comment: EmailJobData is just a object with two string variables

Comment: I mean to say at REST client side you should check if it is accepting an xml response type then this method will not be called.

Comment: can u please explain that. I still didn't get you. How can I check that?

Comment: Use Advanced REST client set contenttype is application/json which is available in drop down

Comment: got it.Thanks. I used REST Console